# Mobile browsers don't support Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing one simple website using React.js + Firebase.
The code is almost done and I did test it a few days ago.
When I was on PC, my web worked well on almost browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
But in case of mobile phones (both Android phone and iPhone), the notifications and data messages didn't work. I tried to find issues and found that the mobile browsers failed to get FCM tokens.
I used Chrome and Safari mobile browsers. Let me know that this issue is from my code or something other.

Please help me with this issue.

Following one is my code to get FCM token.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getToken, onMessage, getMessaging} from 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "********************",
  authDomain: "*********************",
  databaseURL: "******************",
  projectId: "**********************",
  storageBucket: "****************************",
  messagingSenderId: "*********",
  appId: "********************",
  measurementId: "**********"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const getAndSaveFCMToken = async (roomId, role) => {
  try {
    const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: vapidKey });
    
    if (currentToken) {
      const docRef = doc(db, 'rooms', roomId);
      if(role === 'admin') {
        await updateDoc(docRef, { admin_token: currentToken });
      } else {
        await updateDoc(docRef, { player_tokens: arrayUnion(currentToken)});
      }
      return currentToken;
    } else {
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      return 'Failed to get token!';
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // Handle error, possibly by returning null or re-throwing the error
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending messages to browsers on mobile devices through FCM *is* possible nowadays. See also this post on the Firebase blog: [Sending to MacOS, iOS Safari using FCM JS SDK](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/08/fcm-for-safari) and this video: [Firebase Cloud Messaging supports notifications on Safari](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6n4FxuhiJo).

Your code seems to not ask permission though, which is the first step in that blog post, and which may explain why it doesn't work. I recommend following that post and video step-by-step, and capturing debugging information when something doesn't work.